# Turning an ES5 React + Flux dispatcher test into ES6 fails

Tags: reactjs, import, require, dispatcher, jestjs

**Their __tests__/TodoStore-test.js file:**
[https://github.com/facebook/flux/blob/master/examples/flux-todomvc/js/stores/**tests**/TodoStore-test.js](https://github.com/facebook/flux/blob/master/examples/flux-todomvc/js/stores/__tests__/TodoStore-test.js)

**And their js/dispatcher/AppDispatcher.js file:**
https://github.com/facebook/flux/blob/master/examples/flux-todomvc/js/dispatcher/AppDispatcher.js

In their case, the dispatcher is simply this:

```
var Dispatcher = require('flux').Dispatcher;
module.exports = new Dispatcher();
```

And in their test's `beforeEach` it resets:

```
AppDispatcher = require('../../dispatcher/AppDispatcher');
```

Now, in my own project I'd like to use ES6's way of doing things. I'm not sure how, though. The differences between `require` and `import` elude me.

**My dispatcher:**

```
import { Dispatcher } from 'flux';
var dispatcher = new Dispatcher({
    logLevel: 'ALL'
});
export default dispatcher;
```

Which–as a piece in the app–works fine in my app, but the `require` example above isn't having it.

**The part of the test that needs to be converted to ES6's `import`:**

```
beforeEach(function() {
    AppDispatcher = require('./../src/dispatcher/dispatcher');
    TodoStore = require('./../src/stores/TodoStore');
    callback = AppDispatcher.register.mock.calls[0][0];
});
```

But, of course, this does not work:

```
beforeEach(function() {
    AppDispatcher = import './../src/dispatcher/dispatcher';
    // snip
});
```

Or:

```
import dispatcher from './../src/dispatcher/dispatcher';
beforeEach(function() {
    AppDispatcher = new dispatcher();
    // snip
});
```

I'm just doing by trial and error now and it's taking way too much time just to write a *test*.

My thought process:

They require whatever their dispatcher file outputs, which is always a `new Dispatcher()`.

In my case, I'm creating a `new Dispatcher` and `export` that instance. Instead, I'd probably need to not instantiate it in the dispatcher file, but leave that up to the `export`, e.g.: `export default new Dispatcher()`, but that looks awful.

But no matter what I try I keep getting errors like:

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'register' of undefined`

Does anybody have a clue how to get this one up and running?
Much obliged!

Answer (score 0):

The ES6  import Syntax is actually `import defaultMember from 'module-name';`

So in your case it would be

```
import AppDispatcher from './../src/dispatcher/dispatcher';
import TodoStore from './../src/stores/TodoStore';
```

For further info on ES6 import read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import